# /bin/sh: adb: command not found

Tags: android, react-native, adb

When I try to run my react native app on my device, I get the following message `/bin/sh: adb: command not found`. The app still runs on my phone but I can't reload it or remote debug it.

There are many questions like this but their solutions don't help me.

My adb file is in `~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`.

I tried to do `sudo nano ~/.zshrc`, then under User Configuration I added `export PATH="~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"` but it didn't help.

When I do `echo $PATH` I get the following (but I don't know what it means :( ):
`/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims:/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/myname/.rvm/bin`

I guess I should export the correct path but I don't know where to start from. Any idea?

Comment: I'm assuming you run OSX. You have to remember the $PATH at the end of the export PATH command. What happens if you run:
export PATH="~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH

Answer (score 138, accepted):

please try:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/{yourusername}/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```

Comment: Do I just write this in the terminal? Or inside some files?

Comment: I wrote it in my terminal and it works now.

Comment: you must add it in the .bash_profile if you are using mac

Comment: Ty, worked well!

Comment: export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/{youusername}/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH

Comment: updating the path helps me too. One note is that you may want to close and re-open your terminal to see the changes.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin that's not needed, you can just run `source .bash_profile`

Comment: ANDROID_SDK works for me.

Comment: It worked on my end. Thanks!

Comment: is it documented on react native official docs or this is more like hacky way to get it done ? can i get reference link for this ?

Comment: you have to edit 2 file

vim .zshrc
vim .bash_profile

command --> vim = open editor , i = insert   , :wq = for save and close edit

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this. ~/Library didn't work at all for me