# Can't access my android emulator in react native "/bin/sh: adb: command not found"

Tags: android, react-native

I use mac and setting up the development environment by React Native CLI Quickstart. https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

It works for me in ios but in android i'm getting an error.

My steps:

1.open ~/.zshrc

2.add to the file

```
> export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk export
> PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator export
> PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools export
> PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin export
> PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

3. save and run source ~/.zshrc
   4.open emulator, run yarn android and getting the error:

> /bin/sh: adb: command not found.
>
> error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an
> output of `emulator -list-avds`.

> warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync adb ENOENT
> error Failed to start the app. Error: spawnSync adb ENOENT at Object.spawnSync (internal/child_process.js:1070:20)

** **when i run "emulator -list-avds" i can see the emulator**

Answer (score 3):

Run the below three commands before running npm run android

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```

Comment: Running these commands inside the project folder solves the problem for me.

Comment: this might help you  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53755300/7022711